# Die Roller with user selecting number of sides

Tags: c#, random, dice

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to build a die roller game in C#.

The program asks the user for the number of sides and then rolls a dice with a random number.

I have the following pseudocode:

1. ask user for the number of sides.
2. roll the die with a random number with max range being the number of sides.
3. tell the user the number rolled

My question is how do I roll the dice with generating a random number in range specified by the user?

Comment: [Random.Next(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)

Comment: What you're basically asking is how do you get a random number within a certain range. Look into the `Random` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts6se2ek.aspx) class is commonly used to generate casual random numbers.

It has an overload of a method called [`Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx) which generates a random integer that is greater than or equal to `0` and strictly less than the passed integer argument.

Thus if the user chooses an `n`-sided die, and you have an instance of `Random` `r`,

```
r.Next(n) + 1
```

will generate a random integer between `1` and `n` inclusive.

It is good practice to create a single instance of `Random` and reuse it, because if you create several instances close together they will all generate the same numbers.

Comment: What if you have a six sided dice, roll a 6 and then you add 1 - you will have 7 wouldn't you in the case of `Random.Next(n) + 1`?

Comment: `r.Next(n)` will generate between `0` and `n-1` inclusive - so `r.Next(6)` will generate between `0` and `5`.

Comment: I see! I would've thought by specifying the `Max` value in the overload that you would be able to get `n` as the highest one however reading the overload method it states - `Returns a non-negative random number less than the specified maximum value`.

Comment: It's handy to pick a random array element - r.Next(arr.Length)

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(1, userInput);
```

One thing for you to know though is the random function isn't exactly random, its random but in the same random order everytime.. I'll let you look on your favourite search engine for seeding ;)

Comment: If the user inputs `6`, this will never return `6`. (It will return between `1` and `5` inclusive.

Comment: Hah, fair enough. I'm sorry I foiled your plan :D

Answer (score 0):

To get a Random integer between 0 and 100 with 100 not included:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int RollDice(int iNoSides)
{
  var rand = new Random();
  return rand.Next(iNoSides) + 1
}
```

A simple google of `random number c#` would of got you more or less this exact code.

**EDIT**

You have the link to the MSDN documentation from other answers and comments, I know your new to programming but the best way to learn is to try as hard as you can to get something. If you get to a state where your mind can't function any more, posting your attempt with your question on Stack will make people generally a lot happier that they are genuinely helping somebody that is stuck

**EDIT 2**

Following @Rawling's comment, I realised that the overload of the method states that `Next(n)` returns a `Non-negative number less than the specified maximum`.

Comment: If the user inputs `6`, this will return a nubmer between `0` and `5` inclusive. Also, if this is called in a tight loop, it will return the same number repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks, I did Google a number of key words including "random dice c#" but not "random number c#". I guess the key is to start with simpler searches to more complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), specifically [System.Random.Next(Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) should get you started.

```
Random.Next(Int32, Int32)
Returns a random number within a specified range.
```